# Pass multiple values through and process them

Tags: php, jquery, forms, foreach, hidden

I have a form that adds a hidden field for every object in the list and this is then picked up on the next page with a foreach. It all works fine.

My question is that I need to add another variable into that list. So far this is date/time. How do I get another value to be picked up by the same foreach?

Thanks

The Form:

```
 <form action="test.php" id="calendarform" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Export Calendar"/>
 </form>
```

The jQuery:

```
    $('#calendarform').submit(function(e) {
            var form = $(this);
            var listItems = $('.listItem'); 
            listItems.each(function(index){   //For each event do this:
                var listItem = $(this);
                $("<input type='hidden'/>").val(listItem.text()).appendTo(form).attr('name', 'listItem[' + index + ']');
                });
```

On the response page:

```
foreach($_POST['listItem'] as $key => $value){

      $eventDate = trim($value);

 }
```

And finally how I would like it to work:

```
 foreach($_POST['listItem'] as $key => $value){

      $eventDate = trim($value);
      $eventTitle = trim($value2);


 }
```

Comment: where will you be getting all your date values from?

Comment: var txt = $('#listbox');     
    txt.append("<li class ='listItem'> " + dtstart + "</li>")

Comment: Have you considered passing the values as JSON and decoding on the PHP side.

Comment: No, How would i go about that? So far, it all works great with one the one value that is there. I just need to pass 2 values across not just one.

Answer (score 0):

If listItem is like

```
<input name="listItem[0][]">date <input name="listItem[0][]">title 
<input name="listItem[1][]">date <input name="listItem[1][]">title
```

you could do:

```
foreach($_POST['listItem'] as $key => $values){
  list($eventDate, $eventTitle) = $values;
}
```

Comment: ok, How can i rearrange this to allow that? $("<input type='hidden'/>").val(listItem.text()).appendTo(form).attr('name', 'listItem[' + index + ']');

Comment: That cleared the syntax error. Thanks. I am having some trouble understanding what you have done with the form though. How do I get the date and title across?

Comment: I just used the same form field named listItem and extended it to an array, so it may hold more than one value. Anyway I guess you are on the wrong way with keeping your initial "foreach". Try to accomplish it in an other way.